# performance issue : generic selector vs individual binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

so in my page I'll be inserting a series of elements, let's say with class name "element" but some of them will be disabled, which will get additional class "disabled". Now I want to bind a click event to all non-disabled elements, and I was just wondering if performance wise it's better to just write

```
$(".element:not(.disabled)") .live("click",function() { ...
```

or should I bind a click event to each individual elements as they are being inserted ?

p.s. I know .on has replaced .live, but right now im using version 1.6.2, so can't change that

Comment: .live is depreceated, you should use .on in any case...

Comment: im using version 1.6.2 right now

Comment: just sayin... no harm in using the correct stuff...

Comment: Since we're already talking about performance: use `$(".element").filter(":not('.disabled')")` instead of `$(".element:not(.disabled)")` – this way, jQuery will use the browser's native selectors for the initial `.element` selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you should never be using `.live()` any more as it has been deprecated for all versions of jQuery.  I would suggest this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.element:not(.disabled)', function() {...});
```

There should be little performance issue with this because the comparison to the selector only happens when a click occurs and when the comparison is done, it's a fairly simple comparison to just the check the target's class name.

Also, since a click is a user action that occurs in user time and the selector comparison is not complex at all, it is highly unlikely that any delay could be noticable (we're talking about milliseconds here at most).

Answer (score 3):

General rule of thumb: Do not optimize until you identify something as a performance problem.

If you have ten thousand elements on the page, you might notice that the `:not()` selector is *a bit slow*, but if you have ten thousand elements on the page, something is seriously wrong with your design.

What I suspect is that you have a handful (>1 and <100) elements on the page, in which case that selector will perform just fine!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't notice a performance problem, there should not be any need to fix it!

Personally I would attach the click events and then run a check on them. Like this:

```
$(".element").on("click",function() { 
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.hasClass("disabled")) return;

  //Continue here
});
```

Also you should use `.on` rather than `.live` as it is now deprecated. [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/).